# System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ForeignKeyNavigationPropertyConfiguration does not contain a definition for HasForeignKey

Tags: entity

I am using EF 5.0.0 and trying to use it with existing database. I have 2 classes in my model:

```
public class Result
{
    public int DateId { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("DateId")]
    public Date Date { get; set; }
}

public class Date 
{
    int DateId { get; set; }
    string DateFull { get; set; }
}
```

In the database schema the Result table's column is called "resultDateKey" and using FluentAPI configuration I have mapped to that column

```
        Property(r => r.DateId).HasColumnName("resultDateKey");
```

Now I want this same column to be treated as the Foreign Key.

If I use the DataAnnotations (Refer to the commented line in Result Class) it works fine. But I want to do this using Fluent API and trying to do that using :

```
         HasRequired(r => r.Date).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(r => r.DateId);
```

is giving an error :

System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ForeignKeyNavigationPropertyConfiguration does not contain a definition for HasForeignKey

I am unable to see the HasForeignKey() method.

Any idea why I am not able to get this done using Fluent API ?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

---

Comment: I have same question. Why we can specify WithMany().HasForeignKey() and cannot WithOptional().HasForeignKey() <- no such method in helper.